# Automatically open outlook panel with office js

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a question about the office add-in, especially outlook, I didn't find the answer in the documentation, but I would like to get an update on this question: Is it possible to automatically open the manifest taskpane installed in office when starting the application? Is it possible programmatically with office js?

Comment: There are ways to do this in some Office apps, but as Eugene says, not in Outlook.

Comment: Hi @Leonardo Camilo, as the answer suggests, we do not have this functionality, but can you please elaborate on your scenario - Do you need to open the task pane for all emails? Specific emails? Specific recipients? What would be the trigger you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS`  (Office JavaScript API) doesn't provide any property or method for that. There is no way to open a task pane programmatically in Outlook web add-ins. Task panes can be opened by a ribbon button or by clicking on the notification message link. There is no currently any way to set up a task pane to be opened automatically at startup in Outlook.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on Tech Community where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .